# Combine add git repository one repo as branches

Tags: git

I have two directories, each their own git repo, that I have realized are two parts/versions of the same project.  I'd like to add them as sub-directories to a new project folder, while preserving the commit history of each.

Ideally, project_A and project_B would be branches of the same parent git repository.

Existing file structure:

```
project_A
| --.git
| --project_B files

project_B
| --.git
| --project_B files
```

Taraget File Structure:

```
ParentProjectFolder
|--project_A
|   | --project_A files
|--project_B
|   | --project_B files
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a branch on target repo
2. Add source repo as a remote of the target repo (Lookup git remote, you can add local repositories as well)
3. Link the source branch and the target branch with `git branch -u`
4. `git pull` into the target branch.

You may have to resolve conflicts and perform a merge, depending on what changes there are on either repository.

Comment: What is the best usage of `git branch -u`? I have created a branch in the parent directory and added the existing repo as a remote of the parent but cannot figure out the correct syntax to link the source branch with the remote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for you situation, try to use git `submodules`

in your ParentProjectFolder,

```
git submodule add  your_remote_repo_url
```

check the doc http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules